# rails database design - students, lecturers can login. Best way? 1)common User linking to both or 2)treat both as separate models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Lets assume a website whether students, lecturers can login.

This can be done in two ways:

1. User model will be there, and user_type field ensure whether he is student or lecturer. But, in this way, if a student takes username 'a', then lecturer cant take same username 'a'. Since they both are different, for example like /profiles/lecturers/a. Here, user model says 'a' already exists, but that belongs to Student but not lecturer, so what should profiles/lecturers/a say? weird, right?
2. Here, There wont be any user model. Separate Lecturer and Student models with separate usernames. Offourse,we can have a common user model with common things like name, address, country. But, username should not be in usermodel. They should be part of Student, Lecturer.

Just not getting what to start with ?

What do you guys suggest ? 1 or 2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether you really want the username to be unique. Of course you could always have the unique field be an email and that could solve the problem.

Generally, for simplicity its probably easiest to just go with one User Model (differentiated by email for example) and then use a gem like **cancan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)** to make different roles.

For authentication you can also take at many excellent gems that fit that bill, most notably:

- Devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
- Sorcery https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery

Answer (score 1):

I would lean towards #1 but use STI (single table inheritance) - its not always the best solution, but might be a good fit here, at least it is worth experimenting with

something along the lines of:

- use devise and generate a User model and table, let devise handle all user authentication - it will use users.email as the login by default, go with that
- add a 'type' column (string) to your user table for STI
- add a 'nickname' column to the user table, show that in the UI, no need for it to be unique across Lecturer and Student

implement Lecturer and Student models which inherit from User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # all of the devise code
  # ...

  def is_student?
    type == "student"
  end

  # ...

class Lecturer < User
  # ...

class Student < User
  # ...
```

Devise will inject the `current_user` method in your controllers, you might need/want to override it. Normally it would return a User object, you can use `becomes` to cast it to the appropriate sub-class - see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes

```
def current_user
  return nil unless @current_user

  if @current_user.is_student?
    @current_user.becomes(Student)
  elsif @current_user.is_lecturer?        
    @current_user.becomes(Lecturer)
  else
    @current_user
  end
end
```

or don't mess with current_user at all, instead add in your own `current_student` and `current_lecturer` methods

```
# nil if not a student
def current_student
  current_user.becomes(Student) if current_user.is_student?
end
```

*NOTE: none of this code has been tested, your milage may vary*

Comment: +1  Even I moved to 1 frm 2, as 99% of the times, both lecturer and stuent doesnt have same email. thanks, +1. And I thought of the same logic, like keeping the device default confirmations etc at the beginning(jst add 'type' additionally) and once he confirms, he can then follow the process of filling up his profile. I didnt have the idea of inheritance, but got that frm this :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple answer for this. It will be really simple and won't matter so much which route you take if your application only have `Student` and `Lecturer`.

However, what happen when, you are required to have `Classroom`? A `classroom` can have multiple `lecturers` and multiple `students`. It is still quite simple to query either `Lecturer` or `Student` from `Classroom` right? What happen when you want to look for `students` that have classes given `lecturers`? Then you have `Faculty`, `Course`, `Examination`, `Grade`, `GPA`, then may want to define which lecturer can create what etc etc. Surely all of this can be solved using those `SQL` techniques `rails` handily provides but what are the trade-offs?

So I guess my answer is unless you have taken all those into consideration there is no **right way**.